# C#, SQL SP inside transactionScope ends transaction by timing out

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, timeout, transactionscope

With the code:

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope( TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew, new System.TimeSpan( 0, 15, 0 ) ))
    {
      try
      {
        for (int i=0; i<10000; i++)
        {
          dataContext.CallSP( i );
        }
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
        log( e );
      }
      finally
      {
        scope.Complete();
      }
    }
```

If we call CallSP, it may time out.  If it times out, we get the error when trying to Complete() the transaction.

The transaction has aborted. | System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The COMMIT TRANSACTION request has no corresponding BEGIN TRANSACTION.

What is a way to structure this, so that we keep the speedup benefit of running the CallSPs in a transaction, and we don't try to complete it, if the CallSP failed in such a way that the transaction is no longer open for Completing?

Comment: Does you stored procedure call a `BEGIN TRANSACTION`, `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK` in its code?

Comment: it does not call any of those

Comment: The problem has the same symptoms as https://startbigthinksmall.wordpress.com/2009/05/04/the-transaction-has-aborted-tricky-net-transactionscope-behavior/  except it doesn't have nested transactions.  It appears the timeout sometimes aborts the transaction, but not always .

Answer (score 0):

Rather than calling `scope.Complete()` in the `finally{}` clause, call it in the `try{}` clause.

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew, new System.TimeSpan( 0, 15, 0 ) ))
    {
      try
      {
        for (int i=0; i<10000; i++)
        {
          dataContext.CallSP( i );
        }
        scope.Complete();
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
        log( e );
      }
    }
```

The `TransactionScope` will automatically abort if you enter the `catch{}` clause and therefore do not call `scope.Complete()` before exiting the `using{}` clause..